# Scraping youtube video with R, is it possible?

Tags: r, youtube

I would like to scrape / download youtube videos directly from youtube using `R`. So to clarify, I'm not interested in the meta data, video titles, or comments as much as the *video itself* (be it formated as a video or audio file).

Is this possible? And if so, is it legal? I cannot think of a reason why it shouldn't be, given that there exist tools with which one can download single youtube videos as audio files and given also that material published on youtube and openly accessible are literally exactly that: openly accessible and available.

I had a look at `{tuber}` and `{Rselenium}` but that is only good for retrieving meta data, not the actualy video or audio content.

Any experiences or suggestions?

Comment: Not really `R` specific but this should be quite a helpful resource [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/)

Comment: That's great. Thank you! I guess there are some things that are better done outside of R, although I never thought I would say this...